# Store in an array instead of printing out?

Tags: arrays, string, matrix

Hi I have the following code. Instead of printing it out to the counsel I want to store the resulted prints in an array. How would I do it?

```
static void printPaths (String tempString, int i, int j, int m, int n, char [][] arr) {
        String newString = tempString + arr[i][j];
        if (i == m -1 && j == n-1) {
            System.out.println(newString);
            return;
        }
        //right
        if (j+1 < n) {
            printPaths (newString, i, j+1, m, n, arr);
        }
        //down
        if (i+1 < m) {
            printPaths (newString, i+1, j, m, n, arr);          
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a **global string array** and put the new string into it every time:

```
String results[] = new String[];
...
static void printPaths (String tempString, int i, int j, int m, int n, char [][] arr) {
    String newString = tempString + arr[i][j];
    if (i == m -1 && j == n-1) {
        int index = results.length;
        results[index] = newString;
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

After executing `printPaths` method, `results` will be an array of outputs.